# Create Block that changes textures like End Portal Frame

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to create my first Mod in Minecraft. I already got an ore block, a brick block and an item that I get when breaking the ore block. No I wanted to go further and create a block that changes its texture when rightclicked with an item. Like the end portal frame where the "eye of ender gets inserted into the frame". At first I don't want to try it with 3D textures. only a texture switch. After this works I'll try to make 3D textures, but I haven't found any good tutorial for any of these things

Comment: As I said [on the Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/68328-create-block-that-changes-textures-like-end-portal-frame/?tab=comments#comment-329993), this is easy. Also "3D textures" aren't a thing, they're called "models."

Comment: Yee, just saw it, thx for helping